# JavaScript in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, code-translation

I want to replicate any **given Javascript loop , class , function to into its Ruby Equivalent**

and e.g would as follow
 suppose I passed the following **Javascript** function.

> function define() {
>       var x = 0;
>       for(var i=0; i < 10 ; i++) {
>         var x += i   }
>       alert(x);   }   define();

then  I should get replicate to the corresponding Ruby equivalent code

> def define()
>       x = 0
>       for i in 0...10 do 
>         x += i 
>       end
>       puts x    end     define()

similarly the classes object initialization code i.e

> a = new Array => in JavaScript

should get replicate to

> a = Array.new

Any thought on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, pay some coders to do it. The Ruby code you'll end up with will suck.

Comment: Is this some sort of homework given by a nasty professor?

Comment: There are several (attempts at) Ruby to JS compilers, but I've never heard of a JS to Ruby one.

Comment: Sounds like a project, not a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **magic of your brain**.

There is no tool that does that (to my knowledge).  I would recommend you just rename the javascript to .rb and fix the syntax errors.